# Why asp button sends false for dynamically generated checkboxes after second post back?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dynamic

I have one dynamically generated html table in my web application.One of its column list out asp checkboxes controls. I want to select multiple rows(by checkboxex)to publish,unpublish or delete my articles. It successfully publishes or unpublishes for the first postback of asp button. But when i click for the second time it sends false for all the checkboxex even some of them are selected.So I expect it must work for the second postback if it works for the first time because it had successfully passed all the page life cycle for the first time then why not for the second time..I am really confused.Please help me
 Here is my code:

// For dynamically generated controls i used oninit state

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            ds = GetArticles();

            FillArticleTable();
        }
    }
```

// Code for page Load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            {
                string eventdata = Request.QueryString["event"];
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                if (eventdata != "edt")
                {
                    Actions(id, eventdata);
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Articles.aspx?id=" + id + "");
                }

            }

            else
            {
                ds = GetArticles();
                Cache["Articles"] = ds;

            }

        }

    }
```

// Code for Button Click event

```
    protected void btnApplyAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ddlActions.SelectedValue != "none")
        {
            IterateOverHtmlTable(this.ddlActions.SelectedValue);
            this.myTable.Rows.Clear();
            ds = GetArticles();
            FillArticleTable();
        }
    }
```

// Code For retrieving Articles from database

```
    private DataSet GetArticles()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = xenz-pc\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog =MedicalSystem2; User Id =sa; Password =sa;");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select A.ID,A.ArticleTitle,A.Author,C.Category, A.Published,A.CreatedON,A.ModifiedON  from Articles as A Inner Join Category As C On A.Category_ID = C.ID ", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = com;
        adp.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

//Code For Dynamically generating html table

```
    private void FillArticleTable()
    {

        int rows = 0;
        string imgsource;

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

            rows = rows + 1;

            Object[] fields = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray;

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(fields[4]) == false)
            {
                imgsource = "minus-circle.gif";

            }
            else
            {
                imgsource = "tick-circle.gif";
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < fields.Length; j++)
            {
                HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    HtmlTableCell srno = new HtmlTableCell();
                    srno.InnerText = rows.ToString();
                    cell.InnerText = fields[j].ToString();
                    row.Cells.Add(srno);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                else if (j == 1)
                {
                    cell.InnerText = fields[j].ToString();
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                else if (j == 2)
                {
                    cell.InnerText = fields[j].ToString();
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                else if (j == 3)
                {
                    cell.InnerText = fields[j].ToString();
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                else if (j == 4)
                {
                    cell.InnerHtml = @"<img src=" + imgsource + " 'width=16' 'height=16' alt='published/unpublished'";
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                else if (j == 5)
                {

                    cell.InnerText = String.Format("{0:d}", fields[j]);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }

                else if (j == 6)
                {
                    cell.InnerText = String.Format("{0:d}", fields[j]);
                    HtmlTableCell checkboxes = new HtmlTableCell();

                    checkboxes.Align = "Right";
                    HtmlTableCell actions = new HtmlTableCell();
                    CheckBox chkactionbox = new CheckBox();
                    chkactionbox.EnableViewState = true;
                    checkboxes.Controls.Add(chkactionbox);

                    actions.InnerHtml = @"<a href='ManageArticles.aspx?id=" + fields[0].ToString() + "&event=pu'><img src='tick-circle.gif'  'width=16' 'height=16' alt='published' /></a><a href='ManageArticles.aspx?id=" + fields[0].ToString() + "&event=upu'><img src='minus-circle.gif'  width='16' height='16' alt='not published' /></a><a href='ManageArticles.aspx?id=" + fields[0].ToString() + "&event=edt'><img src='pencil.gif'  width='16' height='16' alt='edit' /></a><a href='ManageArticles.aspx?id=" + fields[0].ToString() + "&event=del'><img src='bin.gif'  width='16' height='16' alt='delete' /></a>";

                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    row.Cells.Add(checkboxes);
                    row.Cells.Add(actions);
                }


            }
            this.myTable.Rows.Add(row);

        }

    }
```

//Code For Finding out checkboxes which are selected by user

```
    private void IterateOverHtmlTable(string eventdata)
    {

        HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable)Page.FindControl("myTable");



        int count = 0;


        foreach (HtmlTableRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            count = count + 1;

            if (count > 1)
            {
                foreach (CheckBox item in row.Cells[8].Controls)
                {
                    if (item.Checked)
                    {



                        Actions(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].InnerText), eventdata);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

// Code For Publish,Unpublish and Delete Actions

```
    private void Actions(int id, string eventdata)
    {
        if (Connection != null)
        {
            if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Connection.Open();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = xenz-pc\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog =MedicalSystem2; User Id =sa; Password =sa;");
            if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Connection.Open();
            }
        }

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        int rows;

        if (eventdata == "pu")
        {
            com.CommandText = "Update Articles Set Published = 'true' Where ID = " + id;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.Connection = Connection;
            rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
            if (rows > 0)
            {



                this.Publish.InnerText = "Published";
            }
        }
        else if (eventdata == "upu")
        {
            com.CommandText = "Update Articles Set Published = 'false' Where ID = " + id;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.Connection = Connection;
            rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
            if (rows > 0)
            {


                this.Unpublish.InnerText = "Unpublished";
            }
        }

        else
        {
            com.CommandText = "Delete From Articles Where ID =" + id;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.Connection = Connection;
            rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
            if (rows > 0)
            {


                this.Publish.InnerText = "Deleted";
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could edit your post and leave the function names; OnInit and OnLoad are easily recognisable, but your own code is not. Can you plz edit your post and put the function signitures back on each one ?

Comment: Also, a DataGrid or GridView might help with some of the heavy lifting here; templated controls have a lot of useful features.

Comment: @sh1rts I agree with you.But the requirement is to use html table only.

Comment: You can use html table in ASP.NET markup. No need to hard code it

Comment: @BenJ, I want dynamic html table then how I can put static markup in asp.net if it is totally filled at run time

Comment: What I'm getting at is you don't need to add HtmlTableCells and Checkboxes *etc* using code, you could instead use a Repeater to render an HTML table and this will save you a lot of effort.

Comment: @sh1rts could you please point out the issue? Why its not working for the second postback.I can't move ahead without understanding and resolving the issue.Hope you understand

Comment: I am surprised to see that nobody here can help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Guyz I finally found a solution for second time postback issue.I just added following one line just after the Instantiation of checkbox in the else if(j == 6) block of FillArticleTable() function and it worked.

chkactionbox.ID = "chk_" + rows.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I noticed that might be of use:

1. You can use data bound control or HTML controls to achieve what you've hardcoded already.
2. Every time button is clicked checkboxes are recreated and that means the check state will reset.

Comment: First what type of html control you are talking about?. Secondly Iam checking user selected checkboxes before creating again in button event